# Prevent $ArrayList.Add from outputting new index to host?

Tags: arrays, powershell, arraylist, indexing, output

In PowerShell, how do I prevent `[System.Collections.ArrayList]$ArrayList=@() ; $ArrayList.Add("New thing")` from sending the value of the new index to host?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cast the result as [void], or redirect to null

```
[void]$ArrayList.Add("New thing")
$ArrayList.Add("New thing") > $nul
$ArrayList.Add("New thing") | out-null
```